# getIntent returns wrong intent when setIntent is followed by a rotation

Tags: android, orientation, android-intent

I have the following scenario:

I have a chat activity, in it's intent it gets the email of the contact for which to show the messages, the activity has singleTop as it's launchmode

By sliding my finger over the screen I switch between different conversations, I do this by calling startActivity with the new intent: onPause will be called, followed by onNewIntent, in which I do setIntent, followed by onResume. In onResume I get the new intent, all good so far.

Then I change the orientation: onPause is called, followed by onDestroy, at this point getIntent returns the correct intent, followed by onCreate which has the old intent, followed by onResume, which also has the old intent

I've found this -> http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7f0389f349e1ee3b to explain this behavior but it doesn't happen on my HTC desire with android 2.2, using the emulator I found it happens on 1.5, but not on 1.6

So my question: Is this normal on 1.5 ? If so, how can I change the behavior of the activity so this doesn't happen again ?

I know I can change the launchmode from singleTop to standard but this will also affect android 1.6+ which I don't want because with singleTop, the changing of conversation goes fast (only onPause and onResume are called), with standard onCreate and onDestroy are also called...

Maybe there is something I can do with the intent flags I haven't found yet, the flags I change in the code so I can have a "if sdk is 3" check...

Thanks for reading, Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can possibly work around it by overriding `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and return the latest intent, which you can then retrieve using `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would like to try this but the API description of onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() says "This function is called purely as an optimization, and you must not rely on it being called"; the not rely on it being called part makes me look/hope for a better solution...

Comment: I'm going to try your solution since no better one has come up, thanks!