# How to get getIntent() to return null after Activity called with an Intent set

Tags: java, android, android-intent, orientation-changes

This question was similar to my original question, but I think there is a better way to approach a solution.

[getIntent returns wrong intent when setIntent is followed by a rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348537/getintent-returns-wrong-intent-when-setintent-is-followed-by-a-rotation)

Basically, in my main `Activity`, which extends `FragmentActivity`, there are two instances where in a Fragment I pass an Intent to this Activity.

This is the code that is having the problem:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(...);

    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getData() != null) {
        String data = getIntent().getDataString();
        //setIntent(null);
```

The `setIntent` was an attempt to solve my problem but it failed to work.

What happens is when I click on a link that goes back to my Activity as an Intent, then I go to the next Fragment, then I rotate the phone, the Intent that was passed two Fragments ago shows up again when I call `getIntent`.

So, when I get the data out of the Intent, how can I set it so the next call to `getIntent` will return null?  Or, would it make sense to just have the data in the Intent be null instead?

I am trying to avoid updating information in the SharedPreferences to handle this.

Answer (score 13):

I found a solution that appears to work, but I expect there is a better way to do it.

```
    if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getData() != null) {
        String data = getIntent().getDataString();
        getIntent().setData(null);
        setIntent(null);
```

I think the `setIntent` isn't of any use, but the `setData(null)` seems to do the trick.

Comment: Does not work on API 27, Haven't tested on other APIs.