# How long is a Intent available

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Im wondering how long does getIntent() in a Activity will be available (does not return null). So lets say I start Activity B from my Activity A and pass some extra data in the Intent.

In Activity B I will read the extra data from the intent in the activities onCreate() method.
So far so good. But how long is `getIntent()` available? I mean, if the user is displaying Activity B, but switchs to another App (i.e. by using the multitasking button) and after some hours the user clicks on the multitasking button again (the activity may have been destroyed in the meantime) and opens Activity B again. So Activity B `onCreate()` will be called to reinstantiate the Activity B. Does getIntent() now still returns the original Intent with the extra value or do I have to save the Intent extra value in Activities `onSaveInstanceState()` and use the Bundle in `onCreate(Bundle state)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does getIntent() now still returns the original Intent with the extra value

Technically, it returns a copy of the `Intent`. Generally speaking, it should be identical to the original `Intent`, including all extras.

Comment: So android will save the intent somehow and restore it if needed right?

Comment: @sockeqwe: Yes. Basically, if the user is navigating back to what logically is that specific instance of the activity (e.g., via the recent-tasks list), Android will hand you back a copy of the `Intent` originally used to create your original copy of that activity instance.

Answer (score 0):

From Android doc, `getIntent()` return

```
Return the intent that started this activity.
```

But their are so many case where getIntent is null or extras are null. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372326/how-to-get-getintent-to-return-null-after-activity-called-with-an-intent-set) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944503/android-getintent-getextras-returns-null). Specially on device rotation or from pressing back keys.

But as its seems documentations says otherwise. Just to be in safe side, i will recommend you to do following

```
if (getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null){

}
```

And, your activity code should prepared to handle the scenario where `getIntent` is null.