# android launch By URL, any way to make getIntent().getScheme() as null manually?

Tags: android, url, android-intent

I am writing an application which can also start by clicking a URL from Email/SMS. After clicking the particular link i will be directed to a **LoginActivity** screen where i need to Login with my credentials. I am getting necessary information to start the application in my LoginActivity as

```
String scheme = getIntent().getScheme()
Uri myURI = intent.getData()
String queryString = myURI.getQuery()
```

from this 'queryString' i am getting necessary details for the aplication to show.
such as,

```
final String[] urlParameters = queryString.split("&");
String studentId = urlParameters[0].split("=")[1];  
String StudentClass = urlParameters[1].split("=")[1];
String studentSem = urlParameters[2].split("=")[1];
```

after getting the necessary details from URL i am going to **ApprovalActivity** to Approve a student's Leave.After approving i am calling **this.finish()** to finsh and the old **LoginActivity** from the activity stack coming to front. When i click Login with my credentials again , actually i supposed to go to a **InboxActivity** page where i can see all pending lave requests from students.

But , here the problem is, if i launched the application from URL, after doing an Approval/Rejection , when i login again, without closing and re-open the application, its going to the ApprovalActivity same as before until i restart the application, instead of starting InboxActivity. I found the reason is the 
**getIntent().getScheme()**  still having the old values , which is given from the URL.

My question is , is there any way to make

```
getIntent().getScheme()= null
```

manually. ie, after first time login, (by URL) any way to make that  getIntent().getScheme() as null ?

Comment: This could be solved by following the solution provided here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372326/how-to-get-getintent-to-return-null-after-activity-called-with-an-intent-set

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997662/how-to-avoid-handling-a-deep-link-twice-on-android]. Since your question is missing relevant information (e.g. manifest tag of the activity and how do you "restart" the app?), we can't be sure about the problem.