# how to avoid handling a deep link twice on android?

Tags: android, onresume, deep-linking

I have an android test app that handles a custom URL deep link (e.g. myapp://xxx/yyy) inside onResume as follows:

```
if (intent.getAction() != Intent.ACTION_VIEW) return;
String data = intent.getDataString();
if (data == null) return;
// do stuff with 'data' which is the custom URL
```

The problem is that this code processes the URL again and again every time the app resumes, even if it wasn't reopened using a deep link! So let's say I:

1. run the app once using a custom url
2. the URL gets processed correctly
3. I move the app to the background again
4. I reopen the app as usual (not through a deep link, just by pressing its icon)
5. The URL gets processed again, as getDataString() keeps returning the last URL
6. If I kill the app process and launch it regularly (not via a link) - only then getDataString() returns null and the URL processing stops.

As per some suggestions, I moved the code to onCreate(). This still runs over and over, for example, when the device rotates even if the app is still in the foreground. So onCreate is also not a good option.

How do I avoid getting the same URL over and over when the app resumes?

Comment: From what I can tell, your problem is not so much the url code block itself as the execution and timing of the block. One way to do it is save a marker in your sharedpreferences. When you want to run it, set your RUN_PREFS (or whatever) to true. Once the URL is fetched, RUN_PREFS = false. In onResume, run the code block only if RUN_PREFS = true. So on and so forth.

Comment: have you tried it inside `onCreate()` ?

Comment: Yazan, thanks, seems like your answer is correct, though I would like to better understand the reason for this... If an activity is already live, why is the lifecycle for resuming it via a deep link any different from resuming it via the regular icon? In the former case, it runs onCreate, in the latter, it calls onResume and onStart only.

Comment: when the activity goes to background, it will be paused, and when the app is reopened it will be resumed `onResume()` but `onCreate()` is called once only unless the activity was destroyed, not just paused.

Comment: does this mean that once a deep link activates my app, it implicitly destroys the old instance?

Comment: what i mean is --if there is no other hidden areas in the app, -- whatever way you reopen the app, the current activities `opResume()` will be called, unless the activity was destroyed or the app got killed, the `onCreate()` will be called, this is the lifecycle of activity in android, you can read more about that http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: Yeah, familiar with that. But in this case, I do not explicitly destroy the activity myself: onCreate is not called if I exit the app and reopen it normally from the task list or icon - only when I click on the link in the browser. This might mean that android implicitly destroys the activity during the activation of the link, no?

Comment: yes, maybe you need to dig more on that, may be when opened via the link from browser, it got started with some flags, as SINGLE_TASK, a separated process maybe, or a process within the browser... can't confirm :)

Comment: I have a short update: seems like onCreate is better than onResume, but still has problems. For example, if my app changes orientation, the activity is destroyed when the device is rotated, onCreate() is called and contains the same intent data (deep link URL). The URL gets processed again and again as the device rotates. I assume there are other reasons why, implicitly, onCreate() may be called to show similar results. What other options may there be?

Comment: BTW another SO article mentions verifying the onCreate's state argument is null to verify the activity is really "new" and not just calling onCreate due to rotation or other things. I added this check and it seems to help, though I'm not sure if it's a hack or not. The Android Developer guide of handling deep links makes no mention of it - just says that onCreate/onStart are good places to process the URL...

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments above, the solution that works best seems to be:

1. place the URL processing code inside onCreate(state)
2. only process the URL if state == null

Code sample:

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        if (intent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW) {
            String data = intent.getDataString();
            if (data != null) {
                // ... process URL in 'data'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about if the deep link was clicked but the activity was already running in the background? I've tried setting launchMode to singleInstance and singleTop but neither case causes onCreate to be run.

Comment: Good question, do you suggest another location?

Comment: Took me a while but i ended up figuring it out, In the case where the activity is active in the background and its launch mode is singleTop, you can overwrite the activity's onNewIntent() method and thats where the intent data from your deep link will show up, just make sure you use the intent passed to onNewIntent() and not the one received from getIntent()

Comment: @JStephen answer is probably the best to handle deep link when is running in background. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should process the url in `OnNewIntent` and `onCreate`(neither will be call when become active from background), to avoid multiple processing when rotating, there are two solutions to me:

**Solution 1**:
In `onCreate`, ignore it if savedInstanceState is no null, This solution based on multiple calling is from rotation, and only need changes on app side.

**Solution 2**:
Make the deeplink url dynamic, which changes every time（like `myapp://xxx/yyy?stamp=xxxx`）, and you can check if the url is already processed. This solution can take any case, but need you modify the url ( maybe from server side ).

Answer (score 1):

After processing the intent use
setIntent(null);